# Programmatically select an MFC radio button

Tags: winapi, mfc

When I'm initializing a dialog, I'd like to select one of the radio buttons on the form.  I don't see a way to associate a Control variable using the Class Wizard, like you would typically do with CButtons, CComboBoxes, etc...

Further, it doesn't like a CRadioButton class even exists.

How can I select one of the several radio buttons?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Radio buttons and check buttons are just buttons.  Use a `CButton` control and use `GetCheck`/`SetCheck`.

Answer (score 19):

Use [CWnd::CheckRadioButton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class?view=msvc-160#checkradiobutton) to set select one button in a group and [CWnd::GetCheckedRadioButton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class?view=msvc-160#getcheckedradiobutton) to retrieve the ID of the selected button. Be sure to call these methods on your dialog object, and not any of the radio button objects.

Comment: It should be the accepted answer. **NOTE:** It is **`Dialog->`** and not `RadioButton->`

Comment: I got here because of getting an `ASSERT` on `DDX_Radio` as a consequence of doing a `pRadioButton->SetCheck()` called from the `UpdateData` call which fires when the radio button value is assigned multiple times.

Comment: This methods rely on ID order of the controls. DDX_Radio uses Z-order and WS_GROUP flags. This avoids keeping resource IDs strictly sorted.

Answer (score 8):

Going on what mos said, the following worked did the trick:

```
CButton* pButton = (CButton*)GetDlgItem(IDC_RADIOBUTTON);
pButton->SetCheck(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void CMyDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
  ...
  DDX_Radio(pDX, IDC_RADIO1, m_Radio);
  ...
}
```

but it is the same thing Wizard generates

Comment: This option is better than CWnd::GetCheckedRadioButton() as this uses Window Z-order to locate buttons, and will work independently of the ID value, which can be a PITA to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this one-liner:

```
::SendMessage(GetDlgItem(IDC_RADIO1)->m_hWnd, BM_SETCHECK, BST_CHECKED, NULL);
```